# getting particular table from multiple table in html file using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-table

> Hello I tried to ask these question before but i was not able to explain it properly.
> I am getting an report from an application in html format and that file is getting save in my local directory and that html file consist of many tables in it but i want to extract particular table from the file as the html file is big i am posting small part of it in snippet for understanding.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<html>
   <head>
      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
         <tr>
            <td style="border:none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">
               <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style="height:70px">
                     <td style="width: 80%;border: none;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">
                        Backup job: MUMHOILNDDB01 Backup 1 
                        <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="border: none;padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">
                        Error
                        <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;">1
                           of
                           1
                           hosts processed
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" style="border: none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="inner" border="0" style="margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;">
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td colspan="9" class="sessionDetails" style="border-style: solid; border-color:#a7a9ac; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;"><span>Tuesday, August 4, 2020 11:00:17 AM</span></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="width: 1%;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Success</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:17 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Total size</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Backup size</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;"> </span></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Warning</b></td>
                              <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Data read</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Dedupe</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Error</b></td>
                              <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:24</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Compression</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td colspan="9" nowrap="" style="height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;">
                                 Details
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class="processObjectsHeader" style="height: 23px">
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Name</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Status</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Size</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Read</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:1%;background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td>
                              <td style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Details</b></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">MUMHOILNDDB01</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: #FF0000;">Error</span></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:19 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:41 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:21</td>
                              <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;">Backup job has failed<br />Backup task has been failed<br />Processing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT</span></td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="border:none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">
               <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style="height:70px">
                     <td style="width: 80%;border: none;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">
                        Backup job: MUMHOISAPHIRE01 Backup 1 
                        <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;"></div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="border: none;padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;background-color: #fb9895;color: White;font-weight: bold;font-size: 16px;height: 70px;vertical-align: bottom;padding: 0 0 17px 15px;font-family: Tahoma;">
                        Error
                        <div class="jobDescription" style="margin-top: 5px;font-size: 12px;">1
                           of
                           1
                           hosts processed
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td colspan="2" style="border: none; padding: 0px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="inner" border="0" style="margin: 0px;border-collapse: collapse;">
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td colspan="9" class="sessionDetails" style="border-style: solid; border-color:#a7a9ac; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;"><span>Tuesday, August 4, 2020 10:59:56 AM</span></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="width: 1%;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Success</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">10:59:56 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Total size</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Backup size</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:85px;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td rowspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;vertical-align: top;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;"> </span></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Warning</b></td>
                              <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:20 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Data read</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Dedupe</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Error</b></td>
                              <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:24</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Compression</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">1.0x</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td colspan="9" nowrap="" style="height: 35px;background-color: #f3f4f4;font-size: 16px;vertical-align: middle;padding: 5px 0 0 15px;color: #626365; font-family: Tahoma;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;">
                                 Details
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr class="processObjectsHeader" style="height: 23px">
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Name</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Status</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Start time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>End time</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Size</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Read</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="width:1%;background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Transferred</b></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Duration</b></td>
                              <td style="background-color: #e3e3e3;padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;border-top: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><b>Details</b></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr style="height: 17px;">
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">MUMHOISAPHIRE01</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span style="color: #FF0000;">Error</span></td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">10:59:58 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">11:00:20 AM</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0 B</td>
                              <td nowrap="" style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;">0:00:22</td>
                              <td style="padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid #a7a9ac;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: 12px;"><span class="small_label" style="font-size: 10px;">Backup job has failed<br />Backup task has been failed<br />Processing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:22 GMT</span></td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
```

Now if you run the snippet you can see four tables as actually html file consist of multiple tables and now one thing is common like there are multiple tables with header - Name, StartTime , EndTime ,Status so i am trying to extract all the tables in the html file with header Name, StartTime , EndTime ,Status and export to csv  as there are multiple tables with these header in the html file as you run the snippet you will get the idea, I have wrote script which gives me every thing in excel with not proper formatting.

```
import pandas as pd 
url = "table1.html"
goal = pd.read_html(url)[0]

goal.to_csv("data.csv")
```

but not able to achieve the data and i have tried 'bs4' using 'find_all' property with class but as you see the html code its bit complicated so any idea would be appreciated.

PS : being a newbie to programming and to these platform.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df_all=pd.DataFrame()
df=pd.read_html(url)
for df1 in df:
    df_all=df_all.append(df1)
df_all=df_all[
    df_all[0].str.len()<30
]
df_all=df_all.reset_index(drop=True)
df_all = df_all[
    ~df_all[0].isin(['Success','Warning','Error','Details'])
]
df_all.columns=df_all.iloc[0]
df_all=df_all[
    df_all.Name!='Name'
]
df_all=df_all.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_all)
4             Name Status   Start time     End time Size Read Transferred Duration                                                                                                     Details
0    MUMHOILNDDB01  Error  11:00:19 AM  11:00:41 AM  0 B  0 B         0 B  0:00:21  Backup job has failedBackup task has been failedProcessing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT
1  MUMHOISAPHIRE01  Error  10:59:58 AM  11:00:20 AM  0 B  0 B         0 B  0:00:22  Backup job has failedBackup task has been failedProcessing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:22 GMT
2    MUMHOILNDDB01  Error  11:00:19 AM  11:00:41 AM  0 B  0 B         0 B  0:00:21  Backup job has failedBackup task has been failedProcessing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT
3    MUMHOILNDDB01  Error  11:00:19 AM  11:00:41 AM  0 B  0 B         0 B  0:00:21  Backup job has failedBackup task has been failedProcessing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:42 GMT
4  MUMHOISAPHIRE01  Error  10:59:58 AM  11:00:20 AM  0 B  0 B         0 B  0:00:22  Backup job has failedBackup task has been failedProcessing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:22 GMT
5  MUMHOISAPHIRE01  Error  10:59:58 AM  11:00:20 AM  0 B  0 B         0 B  0:00:22  Backup job has failedBackup task has been failedProcessing finished with errors at 2020-08-04 11:00:22 GMT
```

Edit:
'Dedupe' and 'Compression' are in strings inside of column 0, in previous example i delete them using `<30`

If you want those parameters, you need to go with different way, and from those strings other data is also available.

example for Compression:

```
df_all=pd.DataFrame()
df=pd.read_html(url)
for df1 in df:
    df_all=df_all.append(df1)
df_all=df_all[
    df_all[0].str.len()>50
]

df_all['Compression']=df_all[0].str.extract(r'Compression (.*x)')[0]
print(df_all['Compression'].reset_index(drop=True))
#work with regex
0     1.0x
1     1.0x
2     1.0x
3     1.0x
4     1.0x
5     1.0x
```

Comment: Thanks man ! it worked you are a saviour i was struggling with these for couple of hours. just curious there are two more data like 'Dedupe' and 'Compression' which is in other table but there are of same job report can i extract that details with these one?

Comment: thanks for the response but as you suggested for compression and Dedupe it gives only these two column data what i am trying is to get these data along with previous Name,status with addition two columns of these two compression and Dedupe data in one table

Comment: @rohan no, you can get name etc as well, just print df step by step and you will see pattern